# Rails 3 switching to strong parameters ForbiddenAttributesProtection error not raised?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm attempting to add strong parameters to a Rails 3 application, but it is still permitting all mass attribute assignment and doesn't raise an error for ForbiddenAttributesProtection.

I have created an initializer `strong_parameters.rb` that has the following

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
```

Additionally I have commented out `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in my `config/application.rb` file and removed all instances of `attr_accessible` from my models.

I also added the following to my `config/application.rb` so that I would get an exception in all environments until I'm done testing out the cutover.

`config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`

Despite these changes I can submit any of my existing forms and updates are saved without any exceptions being raised.

Comment: Do you try to use [strong parameter gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)?

Comment: Yes; I'm using the strong parameters gem.  That is what all of this other setup is for the gem, but it appears to not be enforcing anything.